# Tomcat 6 on Win7 run out of command line and NOT service

Tags: tomcat6

Last I used Tomcat, it was v5 or 5.5, can't remember, but I do remember it was possible to not have it installed as a service and just run it out of the command line (there was a batch file that came with it or you had to put one together, it was easy anyway).  Browsing through T6 documentation, seems like there is no alternative to going through the service.

Can someone please tell me this is wrong and how to run it as a service?

Thanks

P.S.:  The reason I use 6 and not 7, in case you wonder, is because it is the only one available in my corporate package repository and we must stay within it, i.e. not fetch software from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please tell me this is wrong and how to run it as a service?

So what do you actually want: Run as a service or from command line? If you do not like the service, just use `<Tomcat Dir>\bin\startup.bat` for starting and `shutdown.bat` for terminating the Tomcat instance.

Comment: that is correct, i do not want it as a service.  but i do not have startup.bat in the bin directory.  do you happenen to know what should go in it so i can just put my own together?  thanks

Comment: in other words, no startup.bat came with the installation.  at least the distro i got.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe the files were removed for "security reasons"? Best way would be to get them from a fresh Tomcat download. Maybe you should update your question with a list of files in bin/.

Comment: You can check the Tomcat SVN for yourself, see https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/trunk/bin/

Comment: sorry, i found it under TOMCAT_ROOT\www\approot\default\bin\tomcat_startup.bat (why the hell would the bin be under www\approot??).  but now the problem i am having when i run that is

Comment: C:\home\SFTWR\Tomcat\www\approot\default\bin>tomcat_startup.bat start
Starting fm_tomcat_default
Asked (and given) winsock 1.1
OpenSCManager failed - Access is denied. (0x5)

Comment: Sounds like you'll need admin privileges to run it, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Maybe you should have a word with whoever is responsible for this environment...

Comment: I am not the admin on my laptop (company owned) but can ask admins to change a setting which would allow this app to run, as long as it is just freeing up a finite list of configuration items and not being an admin all the way.  But in order to do that, I need to know what to ask them to open up.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the `bin` directory containing the startup batch script is under:

```
TOMCAT_ROOT\www\approot\default\bin>tomcat_startup.bat start
```